# Cannot infer Payment Method Mercadopago Integración

Tags: api, flutter, backend, mercadopago

estoy tratando de generar un card token con la api de mercadopago, concretamente en el recurso https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/card_tokens con el siguiente JSON en la petición:

```
{
  "cardNumber": "4509953566233704",
  "email": "test@test.com.ar",
  "cardholder": {
    "name": "APRO"
  },
  "expirationYear": "2025",
  "expirationMonth": "11",
  "securityCode": "123"
}
```

El web service me responde con lo siguiente:

```
{
  **"id": "28e607d8cbceb068e7b99e84c6988216"**,
  "public_key": "public key de test",
  "first_six_digits": "450995",
  "expiration_month": 11,
  "expiration_year": 2025,
  "last_four_digits": "3704",
  "cardholder": {
    "identification": {},
    "name": "APRO"
  },
  "status": "active",
  "date_created": "2023-05-09T01:10:42.346-04:00",
  "date_last_updated": "2023-05-09T01:10:42.346-04:00",
  "date_due": "2023-05-17T01:10:42.346-04:00",
  "luhn_validation": true,
  "live_mode": true,
  "require_esc": false,
  "card_number_length": 16,
  "security_code_length": 3
}
```

Pero cuando intento realizar la siguiente petición para generar un pago en mercadopago con la siguiente petición al recurso /v1/payments (Método POST):

```
{
  "payer": {
    "entity_type": "individual",
    "type": "customer",
    "first_name": "APRO",
    "last_name": "Test",
    "address": {},
    "email": "pedrito@gmail.com",
    "identification": {}
  },
  "description": "Celular Xiaomi Redmi Note 11S 128gb 6gb Ram Original Global Blue Version",
  "installments": 1,
  "issuer_id": "123456",
  **"token": "28e607d8cbceb068e7b99e84c6988216"**,
  "payment_method_id": "visa",
  "transaction_amount": 100
}
```

El web service responde con:

```
{
  "message": "Cannot infer Payment Method",
  "error": "bad_request",
  "status": 400,
  "cause": [
    {
      "code": 2131,
      "description": "payment methods inference error",
      "data": "09-05-2023T05:13:19UTC;e8d91d35-ea9a-4af9-993c-d08a4c058190"
    }
  ]
}
```

De tanto buscar en internet, me he enterado que **Cannot infer Payment Method** se refiere a que se esta intentando pagar con una tarjeta que en un principio fue seleccionada otra, por ejemplo, se ha ingresado un número de tarjeta de crédito para la opción de tarjeta de débito.

¿Alguna solución?

He buscado por todo internet pero no encuentro respuesta.